# Flowbite modal not showing

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, vite, flowbite

I am trying to use flowbite components in my project but they are not working , (e.g dropdown, modal,...).

I followed the documentation but nothing works.

I'm using vuejs 3, Vite v2.9.9.

This is my `main.js` file:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from "@/App.vue";
import router from './router/index'
import store from './state/store'

// Imported css file [TailwindCSS]
import './index.css'

// Imported flowbite
import 'flowbite';

createApp(App)
    .use(router)
    .use(store)
    .mount('#app')
```

modal.vue

```js
<template>

  <!-- Modal toggle -->
  <button class="block text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800" type="button" data-modal-toggle="default-modal">
    Toggle modal
  </button>

  <!-- Main modal -->
  <div id="default-modal" aria-hidden="true" class="hidden overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden fixed right-0 left-0 top-4 z-50 justify-center items-center h-modal md:h-full md:inset-0">
      <div class="relative px-4 w-full max-w-2xl h-full md:h-auto">
          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
              <!-- Modal header -->
              <div class="flex justify-between items-start p-5 rounded-t border-b dark:border-gray-600">
                  <h3 class="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900 lg:text-2xl dark:text-white">
                      Terms of Service
                  </h3>
                  <button type="button" class="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" data-modal-toggle="default-modal">
                      <svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>  
                  </button>
              </div>
              <!-- Modal body -->
              test
              <!-- Modal footer -->
              <div class="flex items-center p-6 space-x-2 rounded-b border-t border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-600">
                  <button data-modal-toggle="default-modal" type="button" class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">I accept</button>
                  <button data-modal-toggle="default-modal" type="button" class="text-gray-500 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-300 rounded-lg border border-gray-200 text-sm font-medium px-5 py-2.5 hover:text-gray-900 focus:z-10 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300 dark:border-gray-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-600">Decline</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem at svelte.

I finally solved it:

```
import 'flowbite/dist/flowbite.js'
...
let modal = new Modal(document.getElementById('modalId'),{placement:'center'})
...
<button on:cllick={()=>modal.show()} >Open</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so what I did to make it work is to create the Modal with Javascript (check [here](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/modal/#javascript-behaviour) the flowbite documentation) instead of using this `data-modal-toggle="defaultModal"` property defined in the html component.
Find below an example with Vue3 Single File Component. For other frameworks the solution should be similar.

```html
<template>
  <!-- Modal toggle -->
  <button class="block text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800" type="button" @click="toggleModal">
    Toggle modal
  </button>
  
  <!-- Main modal -->
  <div id="defaultModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" class="hidden overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden fixed top-0 right-0 left-0 z-50 w-full md:inset-0 h-modal md:h-full justify-center items-center">
      <div class="relative p-4 w-full max-w-2xl h-full md:h-auto">
          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
              <!-- Modal header -->
              <div class="flex justify-between items-start p-4 rounded-t border-b dark:border-gray-600">
                  <h3 class="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                      Terms of Service
                  </h3>
                  <button type="button" class="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" @click="toggleModal">
                      <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                      <span class="sr-only">Close modal</span>
                  </button>
              </div>
              <!-- Modal body -->
              <div class="p-6 space-y-6">
                  <p class="text-base leading-relaxed text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                      With less than a month to go before the European Union enacts new consumer privacy laws for its citizens, companies around the world are updating their terms of service agreements to comply.
                  </p>
                  <p class="text-base leading-relaxed text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                      The European Union’s General Data Protection Regulation (G.D.P.R.) goes into effect on May 25 and is meant to ensure a common set of data rights in the European Union. It requires organizations to notify users as soon as possible of high-risk data breaches that could personally affect them.
                  </p>
              </div>
              <!-- Modal footer -->
              <div class="flex items-center p-6 space-x-2 rounded-b border-t border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-600">
                  <button @click="toggleModal" type="button" class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">I accept</button>
                  <button @click="toggleModal" type="button" class="text-gray-500 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 rounded-lg border border-gray-200 text-sm font-medium px-5 py-2.5 hover:text-gray-900 focus:z-10 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300 dark:border-gray-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-gray-600">Decline</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
      data() {
         return{
            modal: ''
        }
          
      },
      methods: {
          toggleModal() {
              this.modal.toggle();
          }
      },
      mounted() {
          // set the modal menu element
          const targetEl = document.getElementById('defaultModal');
  
          // options with default values
          const options = {
          placement: 'center',
          backdropClasses: 'bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-50 dark:bg-opacity-80 fixed inset-0 z-40',
          onHide: () => {
              console.log('modal is hidden');
          },
          onShow: () => {
              console.log('modal is shown');
          },
          onToggle: () => {
              console.log('modal has been toggled');
          }
          };
  
          this.modal = new Modal(targetEl, options);
    } 
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This took me 2 weeks to figure out, I am using Vite with Vue.

I followed the instructions here https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/vue/

Where it didn't state to add the `script tag`
**`<script src="./node_modules/flowbite/dist/flowbite.js"></script>`**
in my `index.html`

Which is, stated in #3 https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/quickstart/